# My react input type == number is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, input

**Edit2** - demo code is now working

**Edit3** - it appears that the way I'm styling the radio group is breaking the functionality... I hide the input and display a span instead, and that appears to be a problem.

Although I've gained some experience over last several months working in react, something that's always been not 100% clear to me is best-practices with regards to inputs, specifically including radio buttons, checkboxes, and number inputs.

I currently have (what i think is) a bad approach to creating a simple 2-button radio-button-group:

```
const oneTwoFourOptions = ['2 Graphs', '4 Graphs'];
const oneTwoFourButtons =
    (<form>
        <div className='cbb-buttons cbb-buttons-clear' style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            {oneTwoFourOptions.map((d, i) => {
                return (
                    <label key={'onetwofour-' + i} style={{ margin: '0', height: '30px' }}>
                        <input
                            type={'radio'}
                            value={oneTwoFourOptions[i]}
                            disabled={loading}
                            checked={oneTwoFour === oneTwoFourOptions[i]}
                            onChange={this.handleOneTwoFourChange}
                        />
                        <span style={{ width: '100%' }}>{oneTwoFourOptions[i]}</span>
                    </label>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </form>);
```

...which is a form with a div with a label with an input + span, which seems like too much. Dont worry about the classNames / styles so much as the element structure.

However, this post is actually to address a number input that I am trying to make, and that is not currently working (either in my app, or in this stackoverflow post unfortunately). I am actively debugging this post, but see below for a general overview of my attempt at a number input.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      minMinutes: 0
    }
  } 

  handleMinMinutesChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ minMinutes: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
  
    let minMinutesInput =
      (<label className='cbb-number-input'>
          <input
              type='number'
              name='min-minutes-input'
              value={this.state.minMinutes}
              onChange={this.handleMinMinutesChange}
          />
          <span>{this.state.minMinutes}</span>
      </label>);
    
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        {minMinutesInput}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
label.cbb-number-input {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
}


input[type=number] {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  cursor: pointer;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;

  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

In my app, clicking on the number input does nothing. It always shows zero, which is the initial app. I'm not sure why the change functionality is not working, and any help with this would be greatly appreciated. In particular, I would like to avoid using an excessive number of divs and form containers for this single number input, but ofcourse i need it working.

Thanks in advance for help with this!!

**Edit** - if you have a source to the very best, most up-to-date guide on react-best-practices for creating and styling radio buttons, checkboxes, and number inputs, (and also creating their handler functions), that would be even better than addressing my post. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox ?

Comment: I actually dont have a codesandbox acct, i generally try to make reproducible examples using the stackoverflow code snippets

Comment: I think you need to have `this.handleMinMinutesChange = this.handleMinMinutesChange.bind(this);` in your constructor?

Comment: ^ The binding is not required, since he has used an arrow function.

Comment: The code is working fine. I just checked.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code and it seems to work just [fine](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbJoPG).

Comment: i use arrow functions in function definitions for all of my handlers, so i don't use .bind(this) in any of them

Comment: updated the post about 1 min ago with the corrected code. however the number input does not change for me...

Comment: @godof23 Thanks. Not much into react, but good to learn that.

Comment: Is everybody in this comment thread saying that they're able to toggle this input? For me it always remains on zero. Arrow keys, typing numbers, clicking the number, etc. do nothing here. That's the issue.

Comment: @Canovice Works for me too. Did you check the console?

Comment: How did you change the value? by clicking or typing or arrow keys? I'm perplexed right now...

Comment: @godof23 your link doesn't include the styling, which didnt work properly in my initial post bc it was scss. Current post with css breaks the input functionality. css is hiding the input and displaying a span (what I want), but obv dont want it to break the input. What can i do?

Comment: If you hide the input, how do you expect user to change the value? by click/arrow keys/buttons? There has to be something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The great thing about `javascript` is that you don't need to use an `input` if you want to increment or decrement a numbered value. The example below uses React's local `state` in combination with `button`s. When a button is clicked, it's `onClick` handler will update `state` accordingly.

The first example allows you to click on the button to increment the value.

The second example allows you to increment or decrement the value based upon the clicked `+` or `-` button.

As far as `CSS` styling goes, you can find a great resource [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_examples.asp).

As far as `flex` styling goes, you can find a great resource [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

However, in this day and age, most developers turn to a UI framework for quick development: [ant-design](https://ant.design/components/form/), [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/), [semantic-ui](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html), and [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/) to name a few.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { minutes: 0 };
    this.handleIncreaseMinute = this.handleIncreaseMinute.bind(this);
    this.handleDecreaseMinute = this.handleDecreaseMinute.bind(this);
  } 
   
  handleIncreaseMinute() {
    this.setState(state => ({ minutes: state.minutes + 1 }));
  }
  
  handleDecreaseMinute() {
    this.setState(state => ({ minutes: state.minutes > 0 ? state.minutes - 1 : 0 }));
  }


  render() {   
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="container">
          <p className="label">Minutes:</p>
          <button className="minutes" onClick={this.handleIncreaseMinute}>{this.state.minutes}</button>
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <p className="label">Minutes:</p>
          <button className="decreaseButton" onClick={this.handleDecreaseMinute}>-</button>
          <p className="minutesDisplay">{this.state.minutes}</p>
          <button className="increaseButton" onClick={this.handleIncreaseMinute}>+</button>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.label {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.increaseButton, .decreaseButton {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.decreaseButton {
  background-color: #f56342;
  color: white;
}

.decreaseButton:hover {
  background-color: #be391c;
}

.increaseButton {
  background-color: #1c2022;
  color: white;
}

.increaseButton:hover {
  background-color: #5a5a5a;
}

.minutesDisplay {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: center;
}

.minutes {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.minutes:hover {
  background-color: #c1c1c1;
}

.minutes:focus, .increaseButton:focus, .decreaseButton:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm reviewing all of the resources. This is amazing and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Though, input type is number, it will be a type of String in JavaScript. So, it would be better to convert to type Number:

```
this.setState({ minMinutes: +event.target.value });
```

Also, set the initial value in your input field:

```
value={this.state.minMinutes || 0}
```

It is necessary for initial render.